# ACF repeater while loop + foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to cover my basic PHP knowledge and I've stucked a bit. I'm trying to connect my this code:

```
if( have_rows('sales') ):
                while( have_rows('sales') ) : the_row();

                $dataPlatform = get_sub_field('platform');

                endwhile;
endif;
```

Which is supposed to get all the product platforms from the ACF repeater field (number of values will vary from 1 to approx 5). And add it to this foreach loop:

```
global $post;

            $terms = get_the_category( $post->ID, 'category' );

            foreach($terms as $term) {
                echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 game-single" data-type="'.$term->slug.'" data-platform="">';
            }
```

Obviously I've tried the easiest approach like the below one:

```
global $post;

            $terms = get_the_category( $post->ID, 'category' );
            
            if( have_rows('sales') ):
                while( have_rows('sales') ) : the_row();

                $dataPlatform = get_sub_field('platform');

                foreach($terms as $term) {
                    echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 game-single" data-type="'.$term->slug.'" data-platform="'. $dataPlatform .'">';
                }
    

                endwhile;
            endif;
```

But it doesn't work as I planned. In theory I wanted to have data attribute called data-platform be filled like data-platform="value1 value2.." but my current code breaks the entire design because it duplicates the entire div with the certain values, and nest them.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would make you some divs without closing them. What is the value of `$dataPlatform`? Also you should be escaping what you echo using `esc_attr` or `esc_html`.

```php
foreach($terms as $term) {
  echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 game-single" data-type="'.$term->slug.'" data-platform="'. $dataPlatform .'">';
}
```

Update: Maybe this?

```
global $post;

$terms = get_the_category( $post->ID, 'category' );
$dataPlatform = "";

if( have_rows('sales') ):
    while( have_rows('sales') ) : the_row();
   
      $dataPlatform .= get_sub_field('platform') . " ";

    endwhile;
    
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 game-single" data-type="'.$term->slug.'" data-platform="'. $dataPlatform .'">';
    }    
endif;
```

Comment: I know it's without closing because I have a bunch of other, not related to that code (like product content, price, description etc). My only goal of foreach was to work on the both data-type and data-platform attributes. Everything is a part of traditional WP_Query loop. I thought that foreach it's the best way of achieving what I wanted. The end result would be sth like: <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 game-single" data-type="bundle" data-attribute="etsy ebay">

Comment: Can you show the actual html result? the part between the `<div` and its `>`

Comment: Sure, it's here: https://pastebin.com/4aQ9D0a6, I have no brightest idea why in the first product (with only one 'data-platform' it shows entire content the proper way, and in the second, foreach doubles the opening div twice

Comment: Sorry me too and it's hard to tell without seeing the full picture. What is the value of  `$dataPlatform`? Maybe there there are multiple categories or multiple $dataPlatform

Comment: so from the beginning - "sales" is a ACF repeater field in which I have a dropdown/select named platform. So a single product can have multiple sales rows/repeaters created, in which there will be bunch of platforms. In my code $dataPlatform returns that value. In the first product there was only one iteration of the repeater field. In the second I've added two sales rows, that's why there are two platforms that are suppose to be shown.

Comment: I'm glad that I didn't give up